# determine activation energy using the time for maximum temperature to be reached for catalytic decomposition of hydrogen peroxide

Tags: experimental-chemistry, temperature

when determining the activation energy for the catalytic decomposition of hydrogen peroxide using manganese dioxide,

a common way is timing the collection of a given volume of gas or pressure when carried out at different temperatures.
Is it possible to instead use data measuring the time to reach the maximum temperature for a reaction instead.

Comment: Where have you found that the activation energy can be obtained by timing the collection of a given volume of gas at different temperatures ?